# How to save data in .txt file in MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, format, text-files

I have 3 txt files `s1.txt, s2.txt, s3.txt`.Each have the same format and number of data.I want to combine only the second column of each of the 3 files into one file. Before I combine the data, I sorted it according to the 1st column:

UnSorted file:
    s1.txt   s2.txt  s3.txt

```
1 23     2 33    3 22 
4 32     4 32    2 11
5 22     1 10    5 28
2 55     8 11    7 11
```

Sorted file:
    s1.txt   s2.txt  s3.txt

```
1 23     1 10    2 11 
2 55     2 33    3 22
4 32     4 32    5 28
5 22     8 11    7 11
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
BaseFile ='s'
n=3
fid=fopen('RT.txt','w');
for i=1:n
  %Open each file consecutively 
  d(i)=fopen([BaseFile num2str(i)'.txt']);

  %read data from file
  A=textscan(d(i),'%f%f')
  a=A{1}
  b=A{2}
  ab=[a,b];

  %sort the data according to the 1st column
  B=sortrows(ab,1);

  %delete the 1st column after being sorted
  B(:,1)=[]

  %write to a new file
  fprintf(fid,'%d\n',B');

  %close (d(i));

  end    
fclose(fid);
```

How can I get the output in the new txt file in this format?

```
23 10 11 
55 33 22
32 32 28
22 11 11
```

instead of this format?

```
23    
55    
32   
22
10    
33
32
11
11
22
28
11
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the output matrix first, then write it to the file.

Here is the new code:

```
BaseFile ='s';
n=3;
for i=1:n % it's not recommended to use i or j as variables, since they used in complex math, but I'll leave it up to you

    % Open each file consecutively
    d=fopen([BaseFile num2str(i) '.txt']);

    % read data from file
    A=textscan(d,'%f%f', 'CollectOutput',1);

    % sort the data according to the 1st column
    B=sortrows(A{:},1);

    % Instead of deleting a column create new matrix
    if(i==1)
        C = zeros(size(B,1),n);
    end

    % Check input file and save the 2nd column
    if size(B,1) ~= size(C,1)
        error('Input files have different number of rows');
    end
    C(:,i) = B(:,2);

    % don't write yet
    fclose (d);

end

% write to a new file
fid=fopen('RT.txt','w');
for k=1:size(C,1)
    fprintf(fid, [repmat('%d\t',1,n-1) '%d\n'], C(k,:));
end
fclose(fid);
```

**EDIT:**
Actually to write only numbers to a file you don't need FPRINTF. Use [DLMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) instead:

```
dlmwrite('RT.txt',C,'\t')
```

Comment: .Thank you very much...your code are so neat and tidy and it works!! :) you've just made my day! Thank you..

Comment: @Jessy: The code can be done better. I didn't pay much attention to input part. For example, you actually don't need cell2mat as well, just use 'CollectOutput' parameter (true) in textscan. I would also add validation code to make sure all input files have the same number of rows (or the code will not work).

Comment: Thanks ...I wonder why this msg --> 'Input files have different number of rows' come out when I removed the sortrows? and it doesn't when I didn't remove the sortrows?

Comment: @Jessy: This line also extracts double matrix from cell array. If you want to remove sortrows, add `B = A{:};`.