# Implementing sortrows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My question is related with the previous solved question in [How to save data in .txt file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925623/how-to-save-data-in-txt-file-in-matlab).

my problem is that, I decided to unsorted the output, however this error comes out when I removed the `sortrows`---`'Input files have different number of rows'` And no error when I leave the `sortrows`

I'm curious why...is it related to the `sortrows`?

EDITED:
I retained the rest of the codes except I changed B to `B=A{:}`

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using. If you have modified the code yuk gave you in the answer to the previous question, tell us *exactly* how you modified it.

Comment: I retained the rest of the code, except I change B to B=A{:}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't ran the code in the other post, it looks like `A` is a cell array whereas `C` is a matrix.  So, if you want to get rid of the `sortrows`, try replacing it with `B=cell2mat(A);`.

Comment: @Jessy - how about `B = [A{:}];`?  Donnie's solution seems right.  What error message do you get?