# MATLAB - Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows

Hi  I have problem with matrix..

I have many .txt files with different number of rows but have the same number of column (1 column)

```
e.g. s1.txt = 1234 rows
     s2.txt = 1200 rows
     s2.txt = 1100 rows
```

I wanted to combine the three files. Since its have different rows .. when I write it to a new file I got this error = Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

How I can solved this problem? .

Comment: Can you include the block of code where you write to file?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine three matrices simply by stacking them:  Assuming that `s1`, etc are the matrices you read in, you can make a new one like this:

`snew = [s1; s2; s3];`

You could also use the `[]` style stacking without creating the new matrix variable if you only need to do it once.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided far too little information for an accurate diagnosis of your problem.  Perhaps you have loaded the data from your files into variables in your workspace.  Perhaps `s1` has 1 column and 1234 rows, etc.  Then you can concatenate the variables into one column vector like this:

```
totalVector = [s1; s2; s3];
```

and write it out to a file with a `save()` statement.

Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me make an assumption that this question is connecting with your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925623/how-to-save-data-in-txt-file-in-matlab), and you want to combine those matrices by columns, leaving empty values in columns with fewer data.

In this case this code should work:

```
BaseFile ='s';
n=3;
A = cell(1,n);
for k=1:n
    A{k} = dlmread([BaseFile num2str(k) '.txt']);
end

% create cell array with maximum number of rows and n number of columns
B = cell(max(cellfun(@numel,A)),n); 

% convert each matrix in A to cell array and store in B
for k=1:n
    B(1:numel(A{k}),k) = num2cell(A{k});
end

% save the data
xlswrite('output.txt',B)
```

The code assumes you have one column in each file, otherwise it will not work.