# Save a vector in txt file

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save data in .txt file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925623/how-to-save-data-in-txt-file-in-matlab)

I have this problem with Matlab. I have a matrix x for example x(100,10). I want to save in txt file only the sixth column but when I open the txt file with notepad I wish to see the numbers in column.
Hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is related and might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925623/how-to-save-data-in-txt-file-in-matlab?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
x = randi(100, 100, 10);
y = x(:, 6);
save('sixthcol.txt', 'y', '-ascii');
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ansari. Actually one of my friend suggested me these commands and works great:

```
fid1=fopen('file.txt','wt');
fprintf(fid1,'%8.6f\n',x(:,6));
fclose(fid1);
```