# How to save multi-dimensional array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an array `M=(1000000,12,2,2)`.

How do I write it to a file to work on later?

```
save('filename.txt','M','-ASCII')
```

doesn't seem to work...

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) just like the answer from @Shai, you can save it to be mat file

2) if you want to save it to be txt file, you can do it in this way:

```
clear;clc;
M=[1000000,12,2,2];
dlmwrite('a.txt',M); % save M to file--a.txt
type a.txt; % print content in a.txt
M = dlmread('a.txt'); % load content of a.txt to M and then you will have 'M=[1000000,12,2,2]'
```

3) you can also use fopen, fprintf, fclose to save a matrix to a file. check this post: [How to save data in .txt file in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925623/how-to-save-data-in-txt-file-in-matlab+)

4) for the code you have, I tested it. It works. The Matlab version I have is R2011b. please check your code again. The code I used to test is as follows:

```
clear;clc;
M=[1000000,12,2,2];

save('b.txt','M','-ASCII');

clear;clc;
M = load('b.txt','-ASCII');
```

Comment: If I use `load` I get a `struct` rather than a straight forward array don't I?

Comment: @user1134241 nope, I tested it. if you load it using 'M = load('b.txt','-ASCII');', it will give 'M=[1000000,12,2,2];' directly. If you saved it to be a mat file and load it using 'a=load('M.mat')', you will get a struct. One is mat file and one is txt file. They are different.

Comment: For this type of operation are there any benefits of one over the other?

Comment: @user1134241  For MAT file, it can save complex data structure, for example struct data. But txt file cannot. Meanwhile, for txt file, it is memory-efficent. For example, when I save 'M=[1000000,12,2,2]' to be txt file, the size of file is 66bytes. But for mat file, the size is 181 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Why not save it as a mat file (binary) ?

```
save('filename.mat', 'M' );
```

afterwards you simply load it

```
% some code ...
M = [];
load( 'filename.mat' );
% now you have M
% code handling multi-dim M
```